# Select first, nearest date to today

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a few dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format in the table column. how can I find the nearest date, less than or equal to today?

Normally I would use:

```
<= (SELECT TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD') from DUAL)
```

but it will return all values less or equal, and I only want one, the nearest.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Dates don't have a format; are they actually stored as dates or as strings?

Comment: Why are you comparing a `DATE` with a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: `(SELECT TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD') from DUAL)` can be simplified to `TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

Answer (score 2):

One method is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      where datecol < sysdate  -- trunc(sysdate) ???
      order by datecol desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: or instead of rownum one could also use `SELECT* FROM ... FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;`

Comment: @Chrᴉz . . . Definitely preferable if the OP is using the more recent versions of Oracle.